# SAS2XLSX Generated XLSX Under Linux x64 Not Able to Open

Tags: excel, sas, openxml, sas-macro

I have downloaded SAS2XLSX macro from [PhUSEwiki](http://www.phusewiki.org/wiki/index.php?title=Creating_compressed_Excel_workbooks_in_SAS_on_a_non-Windows_system_without_SAS/ACCESS) and [PhUSE Paper](https://www.lexjansen.com/phuse/2015/cs/CS04.pdf). I run this macro under PC SAS  9.3 x64 and Linux SAS 9.3 x64. But Linux generated XLSX is not working. I need to use it for Linux. I have also compared all individual XML files with PC SAS generated one, everything matched exactly. Still I am not able to open Linux generated XLSX file. As this paper suggest same carriage return hexadecimal code '0D'x I am using.

I have also attached both SAS generated XLSX files.

Could you please help me?

P.S: ODS EXCEL not supported by SAS 9.3 and ODS EXCELXP is not able to import again using PROC IMPORT

Comment: The attachments might have been stripped.  Can you link to an upload of them ?

Comment: @Richard I wouldn't encourage XLSX attachments,  they're stripped for a reason.

Comment: Try this macro instead, I believe it works on Linux but haven't tested it either. http://www.sascommunity.org/wiki/A_Poor/Rich_SAS_Users_Proc_Export

Answer (score 1):

This macro is not producing a true XLSX, it's producing an XML document that Excel knows how to read, but it isn't ever going to be importable via PROC IMPORT.

If you need support with this macro, the typical route is to email the author.